# Best way to dynamically replace a HTML Form Field with a different one using Javascript, but have input sync to the original/hidden field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I am trying to alter an existing 3rd party html form on my website, using JS.

I have seen several posts about this, but can't quite find an answer that fits my situation.

The form in question has a Checkbox field on it, and I want to hide this and replace it with a Radio Button. However... then I also have to sync them up so that whatever the visitor does on the form to the checkbox, feeds back to the hidden input field, so that when the form is submitted, it has a value in the original field when the form is posted.

So the new Radio Button field, should have a Yes/No choice, and Yes would set the original Checkbox value to TRUE, with No setting it to FALSE.

To clarity... I don't have access to the backend software rendering the form, so only have option to alter it with JS after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly but here is an example how to hide a checkbox in a form, insert there radio buttons and change the checkbox value before the form is submitted.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const log = document.getElementById('log');
const checkbox = form.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
const checkboxContainer = checkbox.closest('label');
const template = '<label><input type="radio" name="replaced" value="replaced">Yes</label> <label><input type="radio" name="replaced" value="" checked>No</label>';

form.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', template);
checkboxContainer.style.display = 'none';

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  checkbox.checked = form.querySelector('input[name="replaced"]:checked').value !== "";
  log.textContent = checkbox.checked; // Show checkbox value
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submitting
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label>Hidden checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"></label>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that has worked perfectly in my situation. I did have to wrap my code in  window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {}; to make sure that all content was ready, that I was altering. However, I have a secondary issue now where the page load event works, but there is an AJAX call which alters the page DOM, and when it comes back from the AJAX call (via cancel click) then the original page is refreshed and my changes don't fire again after the AJAX call. What would be best way to fire it again after AJAX refresh too?

Comment: You said that you don't have access to backend but you can edit JS. So you should change a code wiсth handle the AJAX response.